# Failsave cant start jetty server because of missing http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd

Tags: maven, jetty, dtd

i cant verify my webapp using maven-failsave because the web-jetty.xml referenced a missing dtd (http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd).

Any ideas? Can i disable the dtd-check?

Where can i get the content of http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

old one should work, I'll look into that, but you can also get it at:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd

[edit] An update on this:

We have a number of redirects in place as we try and keep the really old xml file doctypes valid.  We recently wired up a redirect from jetty.codehaus.org to www.eclipse.org/jetty which has resulted in a number of validation errors on these old urls.  This is being addressed but if it impacts you updating to www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd is the best solution so the redirect game is no longer played.